# image gallery in footer in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a jquery plugin like this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/ which shows atleast 3 images out of the total number of photos in a image gallery and allows the rest to be showed when user presses a button .This plugin is working great but my requirement is for a dashboard kinda look beneath which there will be a footer on which this image gallery will be shown.

Does anyone know about such a plugin. This plugin works fine if I don't use jquery mobile but when I put it inside a the footer in jquery mobile it stretches vertically to the buttom instead of stretching horizontally.

This is what i need

[!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]

Header

[!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]

Dashboard with icons

[!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]

Footer with image slider

[!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this plugin http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

Try this http://cdn.digicrafts.com.hk/u/163440/components/js/JSMobilePhotoAlbum/index.html

Here three mobile galary plugins [5-jquery-mobile-gallery-plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/5-jquery-mobile-gallery-plugins/#.UGQc4U0xqrY)

Comment: I finally used this 1 http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/jquery-mobile-tutorial-creating-a-restaurant-picker-web-app.html